# How prove this two condition is equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha\neq \beta$ be nonzero column vectors in n-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Show that this follow two conditions are  equivalent

(1): $\alpha^T\beta>0$

(2): there exists positive definite matrix $A$, such that $$\beta=A\alpha$$

Comment: To prove $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ use the definition of positive definite matrix.

Comment: Obsereve that $\alpha^T\alpha=|\alpha|^2>0$, so if you take $\beta=\alpha$ do you agree the result follows just taking $A=I_n$? Thus $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ is trivial?

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply by the left the equation (2) by α^(T) you obtain in the right side a quadratic form. if A is positive definite the quadratic form is positive and that means  α^(T)β is positive

sorry about my english